# Problems accessing Auth0

Tags: angular, auth0

Using Auth0 results in **Grant type 'http://auth0.com/oauth/grant-type/password-realm' not allowed for the client** error.
What is the possible solution for this?

Comment: https://auth0.com/docs/clients/client-grant-types

Comment: Please acknowledge the answer if it helped solve your problem? Else leave comments if still have any uncertainties.

Answer (score 1):

See [Client Grant Types](https://auth0.com/docs/clients/client-grant-types) docs, and it explains how to [edit available grant types for a Client](https://auth0.com/docs/clients/client-grant-types#edit-available-grant_types)

Essentially, do the following:

[image]

What grant types are available can be dependent on the `client type` and whether confidential, third-party etc. Please see the docs for the small print on the specifics of this.